# How do you position list item bullets inside a list?

Tags: html, css

You will see that the numbers/bullets generated by my HTML make the elements at the left look ugly

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAb8C.jpg

I am trying to use margin and padding at my CSS neither works. Help.

I want the numbers to show at least 5px from the left of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `list-style-position: inside` to your `ol` tag in your CSS stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why default browser stylesheets have a padding for lists.

I think you removed the padding of the OL tag. Or two margins are adjoining (from the image and ol).

Do you have the code?